# cloudera hbase and zookeeper integration

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh, apache-zookeeper

unable to connect from java to hbase. hbase managed zookeeper and centralized zookeeper  both are running. How to disable hbase managed zookeeper in CDH5.8.>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hbase-env.sh look up for property HBASE_MANAGES_ZK and set it to false if you want to manage it externally

Comment: i installed CDH5.8 on 4 Vms running on network and from my windows  (in same network) want to connect to hbase,.I am getting this error.
" Your hostname, IN-LT-164151 resolves to a loopback/non-reachable address: 192.168.2.88, but we couldn't find any external IP address!"

Comment: something is possibly wrong in your /etc/hosts entry

Comment: do i need to add windows IP and host name in linux hosts file?

Comment: IN-LT-164151 is your windows machine hostname?